# JSON and Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, highcharts

I'm recently new using JSON and i´m not able to draw any kind of charts from Highcharts. Since last Friday i'm reading and reading over the internet, i'm learning a lot, for sure, but right now i'm desperate. I just want a simple bar and a pie!

From my php file, Json_encode prints something this:

```
[["January",4],["February",9]]
```

I think that is the correct format, string with the "" and int without it.

And this is the code that i'm trying (i'm putting the entire example from some web i found):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Project Requests',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Requests'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            }, {
            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("myphpname.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all!!!

Comment: Do you use json_encode() in your php? and JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag to return numbers? It is possble to see live demo of this chart?

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan thanks for try to helping me. In my php? I put
print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); at the end. I think that the php is ok, because it returns something like [["January",4],["February",9]] that, if i'm not wrong, is the correct format. 
I think that the mistake is at the javascript, but i do not know where. Maybe the getJSON function is wrong? 
Other side any chart is generated by this way. The only solution that i've found is putting directly the data by myself, but i would like a dynamic chart! 
Thanks again!

Comment: Do you receive any errors? Could you send us link to live demo ?

Comment: The problem is that i don't receive anything. Json_encode returns something like [["January",4],["February",9]].

And i want to put it in a, for example, Pie Chart, so i'm trying this way: http://jsfiddle.net/Anfuca/2cMzP/ It doesn't work, because there's no json, but you can see the code.
I'm taking this code example from this web: 
http://blueflame-software.com/blog/highcharts-pie-chart-php-mysql-example/

My json enconde is at the same format that in the example but i'm getting lost in somewhere that i don't know.

Comment: I think that the problem is with the get.Json. I just want to get some kind of chart, i do not care what...
Does anyone know what is happen over here? I'll appreciate it!!!

Comment: Try to use $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                options.series[0].data.push(json);
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            }); In php, do you use json_encode() with enabled JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ? Because probably you return string, instead of json with values. How your php file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is ok. The problem was that I was using a ***free*** server.

With **XAMPP**, at the `localhost` it works perfect!

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

One way to sort this is to set the categories and data separaately:

```
$(function () {
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ["A", "B"]
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            4,9                
        ]
    }]
};
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

Your getJson could return an object like:

```
{
    categories:["January","February"],
    data:[4,9]
}
```

and then your javascript could set the chart options like:

```
options.xAxis.categories = json.categories;
options.series[0] = json.data;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying helping me @SteveP. I'm very sorry but my knowledge about formatting and getting JSON from php to highcharts javascript it's still low...  I've tried your code. A column chart appears with the values A-B and 4-9 respectively. But, how i format the Json object like {categories:["January","February"],data:[4,9]} instead the [["January",4],["February",9]] that returns my php json_encode ?

Excuse me about my dummies questions. Thanks so much for your help.